Tests on a remote driver are not executed
Using selenium IDE I have created a series of tests that end successfully. Then I export as junit. After moving the file to its location in a maven project src/test/java I try to run the test ./mvnw clean test -Dtest=test.java.DefaultSuiteTest I get this message
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project selenium: No tests were executed! (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]

In the setUp the driver is remote, I have access to it using the browser
 @Before
 public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<someip>:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
 js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 }

When checking the address I notice that a session is never created.
Does this information give you any clue on how to solve this problem?
Greetings and thanks in advance

try changing surefire plugin to 2.19.1 or 2.22.1 It should work
